Finding minimum-distance mapping between integer vectors that also minimizes frequency
I had this problem in a videogame, I'll try to paraphrase it in terms of discrete mathematics, but I'm not a proper mathematician, so do excuse my language...
Anyway, here goes:

Suppose we have a vector $\vec{v}$ of length $N$ (where $N$ is an arbitrarily big, but finite number) of positive integers less then or equal to $k$ ($1\leq v_i\leq k~\forall~0\leq i<N$), such that no two adjacent elements may be the same, i.e. $v_i\neq v_{i+1}~\forall~0\leq i<N-1$. Furthermore, all integers between 1 and $k$ occur the same number of times among the elements.
Define the frequency $f_v$ of this vector as the smallest positive integer that satisfies $v_j=v_{j+f_v}~\forall~0\leq j<N-f_v$. Since $\vec{v}$ is a finite vector, $f_v$ will always exist.
I want to transform it to a vector $\vec{v'}$ with the same properties, but with $k'=k+1$ (let's suppose that $N$ is such that there exists such a vector). This vector must have:

a minimum Hamming distance from $v$: $d(\vec{v}, \vec{v'})$
a minimum frequency $f_{v'}$

My naïve algorithm for finding a vector series that satisfies 1. was to begin with the vector consisting of alternating 1's and 2's (here $f_v=2$), then to get each new vector $v'$:

split $\vec{v}$ into chunks of size $f_v$
keep the first chunk intact, then for each $1<j<k+1$-th chunk, replace all occurences of $j-1$ with $k+1$
duplicate this as many times as needed to have a length of $N$
reassemble chunks into $\vec{v'}$

The proof that this series satisfies 1. (that is, that $d(\vec{v}, \vec{v'})=N\cdot\frac{k+1}{k}$) is left as an excercise to the reader ;)
However, the frequency will be $LCM(k, k+1)$, which, if they're relative prime, can be pretty big ($O(k^2)$).
So, how may I go about finding a vector series that satisfy 1. and 2. simultaneously? If someone can point me to useful theorems etc., I'd be grateful.

So for a 'non-pedioric' vector, is $f_v=N$?

A vector of 1's would be against the codition that no adjacent elements can be equal unless $N=1$.

Of course, $LCM(k,k+1)$ is $k^2+k$ for every positive integer $k$.

@ajotatxe 1. Correct. 2. You are also right, I edited the base case

@ajotatxe 3. Ahh, also true, they will always be co-prime because they will always be incongruent modulo m for all m. I guess I was a bit tired. Anyways, it still holds that it is $O(k^2)$
